# Как обратиться к ячейке памяти с адресом сегмента 0x9000 и смещением 0x0040 и записать данные в txt на С++

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста как на С++ записать код, чтобы обратиться к ячейки памяти процессора CPU188-5MX.Необходимо проверить правильно ли обрабатывает и записывает значения в ячейку памяти с сегментом 0x9000 и  смещением 0x0040. Стоит MS-DOS и для работы поворотных устройств есть программы, которые организуют работу этих поворотных устройств.Мне нужно узнать правильно ли записываются значения углов с этих устройств в память?

Comment: А каким компилятором? Под DOS в старом Borland'е был, например, соответствующий макрос для создания указателя, а сам указатель объявлялся как `far`...

Comment: Доброе утро.Компилятор Visual Studio C++.

Comment: Тогда не знаю. Разве VC++ делает 16-разрядный код под DOS?

Comment: Добрый день. Вроде как нет. Что брать другой старый компилятор ,который делает 16-битный код по DOS? Какой именно ?

Comment: Turbo C++, Pascal, и из по DOS писать код?

Comment: Ну не знаю, какой именно. Watcom умел, но он старый, и даже до C++03 не дотягивает. Может, есть какой из GNU? G++ под DOS?